# react-select onChange target value undefined error - in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-select

I am new to react/nextjs and im getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')". I have tried a few different things, like using select as just a html tag, I have searched the react-select document, but can not find anything that helps with this issue.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';      
import styles from '../src/styles/Flex.module.scss'

const FlexSidebarContainer = ({ sidebarProps }) => {

  const options = sidebarProps.options

  const [value, setValue] = useState("")
    
      const handleOptionChange = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value
        setValue({ value })
      }

      return (
        <form className={styles.form}>
          {options.map((option, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index} className={styles.form_item}>
                <div className={styles.form_label_wrap}>
                  <Select className={styles.form_item_wrap}
                    onChange={handleOptionChange}
                    options={option.items.map(item => ({ value: item.value, label: item.item }) )}
                    defaultValue={option.items.map(item => ({ label: item.item }) )}
                    instanceId={option.items.map(item => ({ instanceId: item.item }) )}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </form>
      )
}

export default FlexSidebarContainer
```

Comment: Could you share your `Select` component? That would help to figure out what's happening with your code

Comment: Sorry, I am using import Select from react-select - not a custom component.

Comment: Did you try to call `const handleOptionChange = (value) => {`. They may not have `e.target` but pass `value` directly

Comment: I updated my question with the rest of the code. but yes, handleOptionChange = (value), will console log correctly.

Comment: I don't understand, if `handleOptionChange = (value)` works which mean your problem got solved? Or something is still wrong?

Comment: I just tried the (value) when you mentioned it. Sorry as i mentioned im new to react, my end goal is to pass the value to a parent component, but I first was trying to get a console log from the main component before trying to pass it up, and everything i had been reading was using onChange as an event.

Comment: now you have the problem in passing the value up to the parent component or not getting any value from `onChange`? I'm trying to narrow down your problem scope actually

Comment: Nope, your solution worked, I moved the useState to the parent component and then passed the value to a sibling component and was able to console log the value change. The only issue now is that I have multiple select components, which are using the same handleOnChange, I see the console.log for each of the select components but I need to apply each select values to different elements. But i guess thats a separate issue, which ill try to work out first.

Comment: Yeah I think your raised problem here got solved, the separate one (you mentioned) you may need to modify your question or create a new question that would help us to support you again

Answer (score 0):

Select is not a HTML tag here and onChange will not work on it. It's a custom component so event will be undefined. Either use a select HTML tag or if you are using custom component namely "Select" then use custom event handler which will be passed as props to Select component.

```
    <select>
      <option></option>
    </select>
```